# PHP error raised on different server for array

Tags: php

I have been using this line on Godaddy and I had no error.

```
 $bb = ["[N]","[/N]", "[c]","[/c]","[r]","[/r]","[l]", "[/l]","[b]","[/b]", "[i]","[/i]","[u]","[/u]","[dic]","[/dic]","\n"];
```

I have the same line on my local machine and its causing an error.

Havent figured out how to display php error on IIS yet.

Comment: what error you got.. can you explain a bit more

Comment: I get a 500 error! I cant turn error on for PHP on IIS

Comment: see Hanky Panky answer

Comment: your php version should be atleast 5.4 to support this syntax for array..

Answer (score 7):

Either **Upgrade** your PHP version or Downgrade your Code (errm no don't do this!)

Your *different server* uses an older version of PHP (**<5.4**) which does not support new array syntax with `[]`

You can simply convert that to old array syntax

```
$bb = array(
  "[N]",
  "[/N]",
  "[c]",
  "[/c]",
  "[r]",
  "[/r]",
  "[l]",
  "[/l]",
  "[b]",
  "[/b]",
  "[i]",
  "[/i]",
  "[u]",
  "[/u]",
  "[dic]",
  "[/dic]",
  "\n"
);
```

There is a very good explanation of this change in the **[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)**

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
?>
```